# Endomorphisms preserving bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form, graded-modules

Let $V=V_0 \oplus V_1$ be a $\mathbb{Z_2}$ finite dimensional graded vector space of dimension $2n$. Let $x_1,..,x_n,y_1,...,y_n$ be a basis of $V$ such that the $x_i$ form a basis for $V_0$ and the $y'i$ form a basis for $V_1$.

Define a bilinear form $B$ on $V$ by $B(x_i,y_j)= \delta_{ij}$ and $B(x_i,x_j)=0=B(y_i,y_j)$ for all $i,j$.

Let $L_B(V)$ be the algebra of graded endomorphisms $V \to V$ which preserve $B$.

Why is $L_B(V)$ isomorphic to $\Lambda^2(V^*)$, the second power of the graded symmetric algebra on the dual of $V$, i.e. strictly quadratic polynomials? I am reading a proof in which they identify these two.

Answer (score 0):

Since bilinear forms can be naturally identified with $T^2(V)^*$, and $V$ is finite dimensional (so $T^2(V)^* \cong T^2(V^*)$ as vector spaces), you can construct the natural map
$$
\begin{align}
\alpha: T^2(V^*) &\to L_B(V) \\
f_1 \otimes f_2 &\mapsto \big( (v_1, v_2) \mapsto f_1(v_1)f_2(v_2) \big)
\end{align}
$$
and verify that $\alpha$ descends to an isomorphism $\Lambda^2(V^*) \to L_B(V)$.

Comment: How are you using the bilinear form $B$ or the corresponding element of $T^2(V^*)$ in the definition of $\alpha$? Also why are you writing an element of $V$ as a pair?

Comment: Of course we can identify $End(V)$ with $V \otimes V^*$ which is isomorphic via $B$ to $V^* \otimes V^*$. Then the claim is that $L_B(V)$ inside $End(V)$ corresponds to $S^2(V^*)$.

Comment: I misread what you wrote there.  I will modify my answer later.